# Delphi : How to create a generic type programatically?

Tags: delphi, generics, dynamic, rtti

How can I dynamically construct a generic type in Delphi?

Let me explain

If I have an interface `IMyInterface<T>`,

I want to dynamically assign the generic `T` parameter and get a reference to that type somehow.

```
function GetInterfaced(aType : PTypeInfo) : TRttiType
begin
    Result := ???
    // I want to return TypeInfo(IMyInterface<aType>);
    // or a RttiType that corresponds to TRttiContext.GetType(IMyInterface<aType>)
end;
```

How can I build this generic type dynamically ?

One restriction, I **must not use**

```
function GetInterfaced<T> : TRttiType
begin
    Result := TrttiContext.Create.GetType(TypeInfo(IMyInterface<T>))
end;
```

---

edit

I am trying to create a type to resolve a component with Stefan's Spring4d container

For example :

```
function ResolveLookup(aModelType : PTypeInfo) : TObject
var aLookupType : PTypeInfo
begin
    aLookupType := SomehowGetTypeOf(ILookup<aModelType>);
    Result := FContainer.Resolve(aLookupType).AsObject;     
end;
```

My real use case here is that I have defined a set of models (

```
TAssociate = class(TModel)
TUser = class(TModel)
TMandate = class(TModel)
```

I also defined "Lookup" views for them :

```
TAssociateLookup = class(TForm, ILookupView<TAssociate>);
```

I registered them in the container as

```
FContainer.RegisterType<TAssociateLookup, ILookupView<TAssociate>>);
```

I then defined a service

```
function TLookupService.GetLookupFor(aModelTypeInfo : PTypeInfo) : IInterface
begin
    Result := FContainer.Resolve(SomeHowGetTypeOf(ILookupView<aModelTypeInfo>).AsInterface;
end
```

The problem is that i cannot use `TLookupService.GetLookupFor<T>`, but I must use `TLookupService.GetLookupFor(aTypeInfo : TTypeInfo)`

This is due to the fact that interfaces cannot have generic members.

If I define a service interface like so I get a compilation error

```
ILookupService = interface
   GetLookupFor<T> : ILookupView<T>; // compilation error
end;
```

So I must move the generic parameter here

```
ILookupService<T> = interface
   GetLookup : ILookupView<T>; 
end;
```

But this means that I must have an instance of the ILookupService for each type of lookup i want to use :

```
MyForm = class(TForm)

fAssociateLookupService : ILookupService<TAssociate>;
fMandateLookupService : ILookupService<TMandate>;
fTaskLookupService : ILookupService<TTask>

end;
```

instead of

```
MyForm = class(TForm)
   fLookupService: ILookupService;
end;
```

This is why I wanted to define an interface like so

```
ILookupService = interface
   GetLookupFor(aType : PTypeInfo) : IInterface; 
end;
```

So I could use

```
procedure TMyForm.DoIt
var
  aLookup : ILookupView<TMandate>;
begin
    aLookup := fLookupService.GetLookupFor(TypeInfo(TMandate)) as ILookupView<TMandate>;
end;
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of how you would use such a function, if it were possible to implement?

Comment: This cannot be done in Delphi. However I think you are onto something else here, i.e. you are trying to do something with that TRttiType you are requesting - what is it?

Comment: Aha, interesting - I was expecting something into that direction. I have some ideas but have to try them out first which might take a few days.

Comment: @StefanGlienke Have you had any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 9):

I don't think the T can be dynamic, 
The compiler needs to know what type T will be at compile time.

The compiler creates a generic class for each type of T used.
For example:

```
IMyInterface<TObjectType1>
IMyInterface<TObjectType2>
```

It doesn't create these at run time, they are created at compile time.